# react-native android app:processReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, duplicates

react-native version:0.54.2
android version:5.1
windows 10 OS
This seems to be a packet collision caused by file duplication,as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvjlw.png)

I try to delete the duplicate file, but it will be regenerated after Typing react-native run-android. I don't know how to fix it, Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try `cd android && ./gradlew clean` Gradlew Clean

Comment: it is Useless, I try it much times